# How to customize the Authorization header of the OAuth2 token request using spring-security-oauth2 with a WebClient?

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-security-oauth2, spring-webclient

I am trying to upgrade to spring security 5.5.1 on a WebClient call.
I found out that the oauth2 *clientId* and *secret* are now URL encoded in `AbstractWebClientReactiveOAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient`, but my token provider does not support this (for example if the secret contains a `+` character it works only when it is sent as a `+` not as `%2B`).
I understand this is seen as a [bug fix from spring-security side](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/9610) ), but I cannot make the token provider change its behavior easily.

So I tried to find a way to work around this.

The [documentation] (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#customizing-the-access-token-request) on how to customize the access token request does not seem to apply when you use a WebClient configuration (which is my case).

In order to remove the clientid/secret encoding I had to extend and copy most of the existing code from `AbstractWebClientReactiveOAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient` to customize the `WebClientReactiveClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient` because most of it has private/default visibility.
I traced this in an [enhancement issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/10042) in the spring-security project.

Is there an easier way to customize the Authorization header of the token request, in order to skip the url encoding ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is definitely room for improvement in some of the APIs around customization, and for sure these types of questions/requests/issues from the community will continue to help highlight those areas.

Regarding the `AbstractWebClientReactiveOAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient` in particular, there is currently no way to override the internal method to populate basic auth credentials in the `Authorization` header. However, you can customize the `WebClient` that is used to make the API call. If it's acceptable in your use case (temporarily, while the behavior change is being addressed and/or a customization option is added) you should be able to intercept the request in the `WebClient`.

Here's a configuration that will create a `WebClient` capable of using an `OAuth2AuthorizedClient`:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
        // @formatter:off
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction exchangeFilterFunction =
                new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
        exchangeFilterFunction.setDefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClient(true);

        return WebClient.builder()
                .filter(exchangeFilterFunction)
                .build();
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
            ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {
        // @formatter:off
        WebClientReactiveClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient accessTokenResponseClient =
                new WebClientReactiveClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient();
        accessTokenResponseClient.setWebClient(createAccessTokenResponseWebClient());

        ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
                ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                        .clientCredentials(consumer ->
                                consumer.accessTokenResponseClient(accessTokenResponseClient)
                                        .build())
                        .build();

        DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
                new DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                        clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);
        // @formatter:on

        return authorizedClientManager;
    }

    protected WebClient createAccessTokenResponseWebClient() {
        // @formatter:off
        return WebClient.builder()
                .filter((clientRequest, exchangeFunction) -> {
                    HttpHeaders headers = clientRequest.headers();
                    String authorizationHeader = headers.getFirst("Authorization");
                    Assert.notNull(authorizationHeader, "Authorization header cannot be null");
                    Assert.isTrue(authorizationHeader.startsWith("Basic "),
                            "Authorization header should start with Basic");
                    String encodedCredentials = authorizationHeader.substring("Basic ".length());
                    byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedCredentials);
                    String credentialsString = new String(decodedBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                    Assert.isTrue(credentialsString.contains(":"), "Decoded credentials should contain a \":\"");
                    String[] credentials = credentialsString.split(":");
                    String clientId = URLDecoder.decode(credentials[0], StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                    String clientSecret = URLDecoder.decode(credentials[1], StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

                    ClientRequest newClientRequest = ClientRequest.from(clientRequest)
                            .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.setBasicAuth(clientId, clientSecret))
                            .build();
                    return exchangeFunction.exchange(newClientRequest);
                })
                .build();
        // @formatter:on
    }

}
```

This test demonstrates that the credentials are decoded for the internal access token response `WebClient`:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class WebClientConfigurationTests {

    private WebClientConfiguration webClientConfiguration;

    @Mock
    private ExchangeFunction exchangeFunction;

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<ClientRequest> clientRequestCaptor;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        webClientConfiguration = new WebClientConfiguration();
    }

    @Test
    public void exchangeWhenBasicAuthThenDecoded() {
        WebClient webClient = webClientConfiguration.createAccessTokenResponseWebClient()
                .mutate()
                .exchangeFunction(exchangeFunction)
                .build();
        when(exchangeFunction.exchange(any(ClientRequest.class)))
                .thenReturn(Mono.just(ClientResponse.create(HttpStatus.OK).build()));

        webClient.post()
                .uri("/oauth/token")
                .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.setBasicAuth("aladdin", URLEncoder.encode("open sesame", StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Void.class)
                .block();

        verify(exchangeFunction).exchange(clientRequestCaptor.capture());

        ClientRequest clientRequest = clientRequestCaptor.getValue();
        String authorizationHeader = clientRequest.headers().getFirst("Authorization");
        assertThat(authorizationHeader).isNotNull();
        String encodedCredentials = authorizationHeader.substring("Basic ".length());
        byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedCredentials);
        String credentialsString = new String(decodedBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String[] credentials = credentialsString.split(":");

        assertThat(credentials[0]).isEqualTo("aladdin");
        assertThat(credentials[1]).isEqualTo("open sesame");
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi,
I tested this solution in my code and it works fine.

Using a custom webclient seems actually a good idea anyway, as it will enable me to customize the timeouts used when retrieving a token. 
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this - when I tried it in my project, my SpringBootTests started to fail with `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}`
Any ideas?

Comment: @kellyfj, unfortunately not. Though it sounds like you are missing configuration. I'd recommend opening a separate stackoverflow question and provide a [minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That often helps isolate issues like that, and you may even find the issue on your own when building the sample.