# How to customize the Authorization header of the OAuth2 token request

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am using Spring Security 5.5 to perform an access token request and recently upgraded to 5.5.1, and now my client secret is rejected by my OAuth 2.0 provider. This was caused by [a bug fix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/9610) to URL encode client credentials per [RFC 6749 Section 2.3.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-2.3.1).

Since my OAuth 2.0 provider is non-compliant, I would like to revert to the old behavior in Spring Security 5.5.0, and send my client credentials without URL encoding.

From the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.6.0-M1/reference/html5/#oauth2client), if I define a `@Bean` of type `OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager`:

```java
    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
            ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {
        // @formatter:off
        OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                .clientCredentials()
                .build();

        DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
            new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);
        // @formatter:on

        return authorizedClientManager;
    }
```

How do I configure it to use a custom converter to set the credentials?

**Note:** Relates to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68304980/15835039) but addresses Servlet support instead of Reactive support with WebClient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose you have the following configuration:

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          test-client:
            provider: spring
            client-id: aladdin
            client-secret: "open sesame"
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
            redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
            scope: resource:read
        provider:
          spring:
            authorization-uri: http://auth-server:9000/oauth/authorize
            token-uri: http://auth-server:9000/oauth/token
```

In the example from the OP, the `OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` supports `client_credentials` grant to make an access token request. This would be useful for ex. if we want to implement the following (fictional) endpoint:

```java
@RestController
public class TokenController {
    @GetMapping("/token")
    public OAuth2AccessToken token(@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("test-client") OAuth2AuthorizedClient testClient) {
        return testClient.getAccessToken();
    }
}
```

The `OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` provides the `OAuth2AuthorizedClient` that is injected in this example. It can be configured with a custom converter as follows:

**Note:** The following is an expanded example adapted from the [Client Credentials section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.6.0-M1/reference/html5/#oauth2Client-client-creds-grant) of the reference documentation.

```java
    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
            ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {
        // @formatter:off
        OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                .clientCredentials((builder) ->
                    builder.accessTokenResponseClient(clientCredentialsAccessTokenResponseClient())
                        .build())
                .build();

        DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
            new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);
        // @formatter:on

        return authorizedClientManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2ClientCredentialsGrantRequest> clientCredentialsAccessTokenResponseClient() {
        // @formatter:off
        OAuth2ClientCredentialsGrantRequestEntityConverter requestEntityConverter =
            new OAuth2ClientCredentialsGrantRequestEntityConverter();
        requestEntityConverter.setHeadersConverter(headersConverter());

        DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient accessTokenResponseClient =
            new DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient();
        accessTokenResponseClient.setRequestEntityConverter(requestEntityConverter);
        // @formatter:on

        return accessTokenResponseClient;
    }

    private static <T extends AbstractOAuth2AuthorizationGrantRequest> Converter<T, HttpHeaders> headersConverter() {
        // @formatter:off
        Converter<T, ClientRegistration> clientRegistrationConverter =
            AbstractOAuth2AuthorizationGrantRequest::getClientRegistration;
        return clientRegistrationConverter
            .andThen((clientRegistration) -> {
                HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));
                headers.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE + ";charset=UTF-8"));
                headers.setBasicAuth(clientRegistration.getClientId(), clientRegistration.getClientSecret());
                return headers;
            });
        // @formatter:on
    }
```

If we wanted to support the `authorization_code` grant for logging into the application, we could use the following configuration (with the above methods and `@Bean` definitions contained within):

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .oauth2Login(oauth2Login -> oauth2Login
                .tokenEndpoint(tokenEndpoint -> tokenEndpoint
                    .accessTokenResponseClient(authorizationCodeAccessTokenResponseClient())));
        // @formatter:on

        return http.build();        
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest> authorizationCodeAccessTokenResponseClient() {
        // @formatter:off
        OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter requestEntityConverter =
            new OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter();
        requestEntityConverter.setHeadersConverter(headersConverter());

        DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient accessTokenResponseClient =
            new DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient();
        accessTokenResponseClient.setRequestEntityConverter(requestEntityConverter);
        // @formatter:on

        return accessTokenResponseClient;
    }

    // ...

}
```

Comment: How does it work when you are not using Servlet or Reactive (like batch job or test script)?

Comment: @BakulG take a look at the docs on [OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/client/core.html#oauth2Client-authorized-manager-provider). You'll want to read about `AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager`.